# How to set collection in query in SolrJ

Tags: java, solr, datastax, solrj

I'm working on a system that uses SolrJ on top of DSE for searching purposes. Currently, I'm implementing search features using SolrJ in Java. I created the SolrClient using base URL (http://localhost:PORT/solr) and I'm trying to specify the collection when requesting query

```
client.query("collectionName", query);
```

However, it seems to me that SolrJ is ignoring collection because I'm getting the following error:

```
/solr/update The requested resource is not available.
```

When I'm adding a collection to SolrClient URL instead of in query function, it works fine. This solution is blocking me from using a single client to request for many collections, so I want to use the first one. Anyone encountered this?

**EDIT:**
I've checked also on 6.6. Still the same. Full error:

> Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr: Expected mime type
>   application/octet-stream but got text/html. Apache Tomcat/8.0.47 - Error
>   reportH1
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;}
>   H2
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;}
>   H3
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;}
>   BODY
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;}
>   B
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A
>   {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px;
>   background-color: #525D76; border: none;}
>
> ## HTTP Status 404 - /solr/update
>
> **type** Status report
>
> **message**
>   /solr/update
>
> **description** The requested resource
>   is not available.
>
> #### Apache
>   Tomcat/8.0.47
>
> org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:
>   Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr: Expected mime type
>   application/octet-stream but got text/html. Apache Tomcat/8.0.47 - Error
>   reportH1
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;}
>   H2
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;}
>   H3
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;}
>   BODY
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;}
>   B
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A
>   {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px;
>   background-color: #525D76; border: none;}
>
> ## HTTP Status 404 - /solr/update
>
> **type** Status report
>
> **message**
>   /solr/update
>
> **description** The requested resource
>   is not available.
>
> #### Apache
>   Tomcat/8.0.47

Comment: btw, what version of DSE is used?

Comment: 6.0 or 6.1, depends from env

Comment: can you post a minimal reproducible code? Because my code (see 2nd answer) works just fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, that's really strange - just tested on the DSE 6.0.2 in my test environment - works just fine for my tables (with standard SolrJ client 6.6.0):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
  <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
  <version>6.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SolrServerException, IOException {
    String url = "http://192.168.0.10:8983/solr";

    SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(url).build();
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setQuery("*:*");
    query.addFilterQuery("user:\"krystina.morissette\"");
    query.setRows(10);
    QueryResponse response = client.query("gatling.user_tokens", query);
    SolrDocumentList list = response.getResults();
    System.out.println("Num found=" + list.getNumFound());
    for (SolrDocument doc: list) {
        System.out.println(doc);
    }
}
```

Gives me following:

```
Num found=4
SolrDocument{_uniqueKey=["krystina.morissette","36c8a420-b91f-477c-88b4-59ca8c59c69e"], expires=Wed Jul 25 11:42:13 CEST 2018, created=Wed Jul 25 11:12:13 CEST 2018, id=36c8a420-b91f-477c-88b4-59ca8c59c69e, user=krystina.morissette, nonce=-2015059461}
SolrDocument{_uniqueKey=["krystina.morissette","9ab1c4be-6764-429b-baeb-923ae7139aa9"], expires=Wed Jul 25 11:45:34 CEST 2018, created=Wed Jul 25 11:15:34 CEST 2018, id=9ab1c4be-6764-429b-baeb-923ae7139aa9, user=krystina.morissette, nonce=-239263702}
SolrDocument{_uniqueKey=["krystina.morissette","8bff6a10-06b4-4473-876d-8380af0568cc"], expires=Wed Jul 25 11:47:48 CEST 2018, created=Wed Jul 25 11:17:48 CEST 2018, id=8bff6a10-06b4-4473-876d-8380af0568cc, user=krystina.morissette, nonce=-658876494}
SolrDocument{_uniqueKey=["krystina.morissette","3f011a59-5bdc-4b7e-b465-d83c29cb333f"], expires=Wed Jul 25 11:49:12 CEST 2018, created=Wed Jul 25 11:19:12 CEST 2018, id=3f011a59-5bdc-4b7e-b465-d83c29cb333f, user=krystina.morissette, nonce=-583776467}
```

Comment: I've got exactly same code, and I'm getting an error. 0o

Comment: Can you check on SolrJ 7.4?

Comment: Edited with additional check on SolrJ 6.6 with just the same code. Gimme a moment to prepare minimal code.

Comment: works just fine with 7.4.0 - I think that the problem is that your query is trying to perform update part of the document, or insert new one.  As I mentioned in my first answer, the HTTP Update API is completely removed in DSE 6 - you must insert/update data using CQL

Comment: Yup, I've found guilty line. I'm using 
    solrClient.commit();
to prepopulate solr with data. This is causing error. So I guess the only way to enforce commit is to switch to your driver?

Comment: Yes, you can do the any query and pass `commit` parameter - see the docs for precise syntax

Answer (score 1):

Usage of Solr HTTP API is really discouraged - it's better to use [CQL integration](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/search/siQueryTOC.html):

- update HTTP API is completely removed in DSE 6, together with other APIs, like, core management, delete by query, etc.;
- when you're using CQL, DSE Search is able to perform better routing of requests based on the different statistics, like, indexing status, etc.;
- you can use the same driver as for normal CQL queries;
- [CQL syntax for DSE Search](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/search/siQuerySyntax.html#siQuerySyntax) is quite flexible, and allows to create quite complex queries, including faceting.
- ...

DSE Search documentation has quite many examples on its use.

Comment: It's all fine until you need to use Spring Data Cassandra. When this comes true, using CQL integration for Solr is one big pain. I was trying this, but pagination is impossible to implement using spring data + DSE CQL Integration. Anyway, +1 for your answer because someone searching for information may be directed in a good way. But it's not helpful for me in any way.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to use Spring Data Cassandra because of not very optimal implementation.

Comment: I fully agree with you. Sometimes we are forced to choose not the best solutions. For everyone that is not forced to do so - leave spring data alone!